# Sum all columns but one in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Basically, all columns except a particular one must be summed. I came up with two closely related solutions:

```
def collapse(arr, i):
    return np.hstack((arr[:,i,None], np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(arr.shape[1]) if j != i]], axis=1, keepdims=True)))

def collapse_transpose(arr, i):
    return np.vstack((arr[:,i], np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(arr.shape[1]) if j != i]], axis=1))).T
```

Example:

```
In [42]: arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [44]: collapse(arr, 0)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  3],
       [ 3,  9],
       [ 6, 15]])
```

I thought the later would be faster, but it came out to be slower. Anyway, I don't like the `vstack` and `hstack` calls, since they can be slow on huge inputs. Are there any ways to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating just 2 arrays

```
In [282]: (arr[:,i], np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]], 
    axis=1))Out[282]: (array([0, 3, 6]), array([ 3,  9, 15]))

In [283]: (arr[:,i,None], np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]], axis=1, keepdims=True))
Out[283]: 
(array([[0],
       [3],
       [6]]), array([[ 3],
       [ 9],
       [15]]))
```

`vstack` and `hstack` both use `concatenate`.  They just work on different axes and massage the inputs in different ways to ensure they have the correct number of dimensions.

It seems to me that the versions are basically equivalent.  You could call `concatenate` directly, which might shave a % or two off.  But the concatenation isn't the biggest time consumer in this case.

```
np.concatenate((arr[:,i,None], 
   np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]], axis=1, keepdims=True)), 
   axis=1)
```

Beyond that look at the timing for the individual pieces.  Is `arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]],axis=1)` as fast as it could be?  How about summing it all, and subtracting the `ith` row?

```
In [310]: timeit arr.sum(1)-arr[:,i]
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.7 us per loop

In [311]: timeit np.sum(arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]], axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 us per loop
```

Comment: "Beyond that look at the timing for the individual pieces. Is arr[:,[j for j in xrange(3) if j != i]],axis=1) as fast as it could be? How about summing it all, and subtracting the ith row?" - this is a nice suggestion, it really does win some time.